# Use default SqlContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following code, which should tell Spark to use the default database schema:

```
sqlContext.sql(s"use default")
```

When I am running this code, I get the following error on the above line:

```
[1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but identifier use found

use default
^
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but identifier use found

use default
^
```

What does this mean?
Why is it expecting `with`?

Answer (score 0):

Database commands are meaningful only for `o.a.s.sql.hive.HiveContex` (Spark < 2.0.0) or `o.a.s.sql.SparkSession` initialized with Hive support (Spark 2.0.0+) but it looks like your using standard `o.a.s.sql.SQLContext` which doesn't support databases.

In other words:

- Use Spark binaries built with Hive support.
- Initialize `SQLContext` with `HiveContext`.